# Can I get past the rocks in the Jarn mines?

Tags: magicka

When finally entering the Jarn mines in chapter 8, you come across an examinable pile of rocks:

[image: Look, rocks!]

Once examined, your character ponders what is behind them, and if there is another way around. Does this simply refer to the other path, or is there some way to get rid of the rocks that I failed to come up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It is not possible to get past them by any conventional means, and there is no playable area or easter egg behind them. It may be possible to blast yourself over top of the area with [ARSE] mines, but the level simply curves around to where the tunnel exit would presumably be.

Source: 70 hours played including the "Sherlock Holmes" achievement - Find all secret areas in the game.

It isn't a secret area, and there is no way to get past it, similar to the log blocking the road in Chapter 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can get past them, but it is in the next area it is the place where the wooden tower is standing, and when you examine it it says that it looks unstable.  I couldn't figure out how to knock it down so I just teleported across.  It is just Sam and Frodo spooning from Lord of the Rings, and you can pick up Sting but in this it is called Stung.  It says it glows when enemies are near but I haven't noticed it ever glow.

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty convincing. I'll need you to explain how, exactly, one can get past the rocks. Perhaps provide some screenshots or a video?